# Is there any way in LINQ to pass value from the selected object

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core, lambda

```cs
MedicalPrescription.CreditItemDetails = 
    (from MB in WYNKContext.MedicalBillMaster.Where(x => x.TransactionId == TC && x.CMPID == CmpID && x.ID == MedBillID )
        join med in WYNKContext.MedicalBillTran on MB.ID equals med.MedicalBillID
         select new CreditItemDetails
         {
            Amount = med.ReturnQuantity != null ? Convert.ToDecimal(med.ReturnQuantity) * Convert.ToDecimal(med.ItemRate) : Convert.ToDecimal(med.Quantity) * Convert.ToDecimal(med.ItemRate),
            GrossAmount =  (med.ReturnQuantity != null ? Convert.ToDecimal(med.ReturnQuantity) * Convert.ToDecimal(med.ItemRate) : Convert.ToDecimal(med.Quantity) * Convert.ToDecimal(med.ItemRate)) - Convert.ToDecimal(med.DiscountAmount),
            // some more properties
        }).ToList();
```

how to use resulted value in selected new CreditItemDetails for further calculation...
Example
*if we get value in Amount for further calculation i need to pass resulted value in another calculation for Grossamount = resulted Amount value  * Discount / 100 like this i need to do.. Is there any way to do like that. Thanks in advance

Comment: What about read only properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you need let

```
MedicalPrescription.CreditItemDetails = 
(from MB in WYNKContext.MedicalBillMaster.Where(x => x.TransactionId == TC && x.CMPID == CmpID && x.ID == MedBillID )
    join med in WYNKContext.MedicalBillTran on MB.ID equals med.MedicalBillID
     let Amount = med.ReturnQuantity != null ? Convert.ToDecimal(med.ReturnQuantity) * Convert.ToDecimal(med.ItemRate) : Convert.ToDecimal(med.Quantity) * Convert.ToDecimal(med.ItemRate),
     select new CreditItemDetails
     {
        Amount = Amount,
        Grossamount = Amount * Discount / 100
    }).ToList();
```

[Let](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/let-clause)

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you to transfer responsibility of any calculations from linq to object himself.

You can create **get only** prop like this:

```
public CreditItemDetails()
{
    public decimal Grossamount => Amount * GrossAmount / 100
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Option A. let clause

You can use the let clause:

> ```
> string[] names = { "Svetlana Omelchenko", "Claire O'Donnell", "Sven Mortensen", "Cesar Garcia" };
> IEnumerable<string> queryFirstNames =
>    from name in names
>    let firstName = name.Split(' ')[0]
>    select firstName;
>
> foreach (string s in queryFirstNames)
>    Console.Write(s + " ");
> //Output: Svetlana Claire Sven Cesar
> ```

Reference: *let clause* in [Query expression basics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/query-expression-basics)

## Option B. Use intermediate objects

```
...
select
         {
            (decimal?) med.ReturnQuantity,
            (decimal?) med.ItemRate
            (decimal?) med.Quantity
            ...
        }).ToList() // Hit the database, it may not be necessary
          .Select( med => new 
               {
                   Amount = ...
                   ...
               })
          .Select( med => new CreditItemDetails
               {
                   Amount,
                   GrossAmount = Amount * xxx
               });
```