# Adding Summed columns together using Linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity

I am wondering if there is an easier way of adding together summed columns inside a group by query using Linq. I am wanting to check wether column1 + column2 is greater than 2250, and if so do something...

Below is a snippet of code im using, a much slimmed down version for use here

```
from contact in _db.Worksheets
                         join person in _db.MyTable on contact.Email equals 
                         person.EmailAddress

                         orderby contact.ShiftDate ascending
                         select new

                         {
                             EmployeeNumber = person.EmployeeNumber,
                             Overtime1= contact.Overtime1,
                             Overtime2= contact.Overtime2,
                             ShiftDate = contact.ShiftDate,
                                                        

                         } into t1                       
                         group t1 by t1.EmployeeNumber into pg
                         select (new
                         {
                              OvertimeTotal = pg.Sum(x => x.ShiftDate >= vStart1 && x.ShiftDate <= vEnd1 ? x.Overtime1 : 0)
                             + pg.Sum(x => x.ShiftDate >= vStart1 && x.ShiftDate <= vEnd1 ? x.Overtime2 : 0) > 2250 (....then do something)
```

I was wondering if you could do something like the below. (Which I have tried and it doesnt work)

I am using entity framework too, so realise there may be complications converting this type of query

```
OvertimeTotal = pg.Sum(x => x.ShiftDate >= vStart1 && x.ShiftDate <= vEnd1 ? x.Overtime1 + x.Overtime2 : 0)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67225243/9067162

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you specify what you want when there is overtime. The following will return the employee numbers with overtime.

The approach is a little different from yours, as it filters the worksheet records before joining with the person records for optimization reasons. It then filters to just the employees that have overtime.

I'm assuming an employee has overtime if overtime1 + overtime2 of all their shifts in the specified date range adds up to more than 2250.

```
var employeesWithOvertime = _db.Worksheets
    .Where(w => w.ShiftDate >= vStart1 && w.ShiftDate <= vEnd1)
    .Join(_db.MyTable, w => w.Email, p => p.EmailAddress, (w, p) => new
    {
        EmployeeNumber = p.EmployeeNumber,
        Overtime1 = w.Overtime1,
        Overtime2 = w.Overtime2
    })
    .GroupBy(x => x.EmployeeNumber)
    .Select(g => new 
    { 
        EmployeeNumber = g.Key,
        OvertimeTotal = g.Sum(x => x.Overtime1 + x.Overtime2)
    })
    .Where(x => x.OvertimeTotal > 2250);
```